# Reference to Mock static void method

Tags: java, mockito

I have been looking around for some example of mocking static void method but can't find any.
Either we have example of mocking static method or mocking void method.

Please share any reference or example for the same.

PS: I am using Mockito-inline 3.6.28

Comment: Ayush , you may have to explore libraries like PowerMock (https://dzone.com/articles/using-powermock-mock-static) that make it significantly easier to achieve static method mocking or void method mocking. If there is a specific question , the forum members can answer that.

Comment: Mockito 3.4.0 introduced the `Mockito.mockStatic()`. No need to switch to PowerMock for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mockito.mockStatic()` with `thenAnswer()`.

Suppose that you want to mock this `hello()` method:

```
public class ClassToMock {

    public static void hello() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

You can write a test like this:

```
@Test
public void testStaticHello() {

    ClassToMock.hello(); // Prints "hello"

    try (MockedStatic<ClassToMock> staticMock = Mockito.mockStatic(ClassToMock.class)) {

        staticMock.when(() -> ClassToMock.hello())
                .thenAnswer(ignore -> {
                    System.out.println("Mocked");
                    return null;
                });

        ClassToMock.hello();  // Prints "Mocked"
    }
}
```